# fold expressions using a function recursively

Tags: c++, fold

I have written an accumulate function similar to [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) that works on a [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). The goal is to remove the loop using fold expressions.

This code currently works in c++17:

```
#include <array>

template<class U, class F>
class array_accumulate_helper
{
public:
    array_accumulate_helper(U& u, F f)
        : r(u), f(f)
    {
    }

    array_accumulate_helper& operator<<(const U& u)
    {
        r = f(r, u);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    F f;
    U& r;
};

template<class U, std::size_t N, class F, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr U array_accumulate_impl(const std::array<U, N>& u, U r, F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    array_accumulate_helper h(r, f);
    (h << ... << u[Is]);
    return r;
}

template<class U, std::size_t N, class F>
constexpr U accumulate(const std::array<U, N>& u, U r, F f)
{
    return array_accumulate_impl(u, r, f, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

template<class U, std::size_t N>
constexpr U accumulate(const std::array<U, N>& u)
{
    return accumulate(u, {}, [](const U& a, const U& b) { return a + b; });
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite `array_accumulate_impl` using a fold expression that doesn't use `array_accumulate_helper`?

I can use a fold expression with an operator.
ie. using `<<` in `array_accumulate_impl` above.

I have been unable to write one using a function recursively.
ie. for a `std::array<int, 3>` it should expand to:

```
f(f(f(r, a[0]), a[1]), a[2]);
```

Comment: Can you add a `main` that exercises the code a little? I couldn't get it to work without making the member functions in `array_accumulate_helper` `constexpr` too. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Mf7KdK)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately c++ [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) supports only binary operators: "any of the following 32 binary operators: + - * / % ^ & | = < > << >> += -= *= /= %= ^= &= |= <<= >>= == != <= >= && || , .* ->*." So you can't call your custom function in pack expansion without using a wrapper.

But if your function accepts a variadic number of arguments you can use std::apply

```
static constexpr std::array arr{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

static constexpr auto sum = [](auto&&... items) {
  return (... + items);
};

static constexpr auto accumulate = [](auto&& fn, const auto& u) {
  return std::apply([fn = std::forward<decltype(fn)>(fn)](auto... item) { return fn(item...); }, u);
};

constexpr auto result = accumulate(sum, arr);
```

Example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/foc866).

Otherwise, you can take advantage of the comma operator:

```
static constexpr std::array arr{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

static constexpr auto accumulate_impl = [](const auto& a, auto init, auto&& fn) {
  return std::apply([fn = std::forward<decltype(fn)>(fn), &init](auto... items) {
    ((void)(init = fn(std::move(init), items)), ...);
    return init;
  }, a);
};

template<class U, std::size_t N>
static constexpr U accumulate(const std::array<U, N>& u) {
  return accumulate_impl(u, U{},  [](auto&& a, auto&& b){return a+b;});
}

static constexpr auto result = accumulate(arr);
```

Example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4rWPef).

Comment: Also worthwhile: [std::plus<void>](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus_void)

Comment: Nice. Thanks for expanding my knowledge.